# How to use curl -4 http://localhost in the Docker part 3 tutorial?

Tags: docker, curl, port

Using the Docker tutorial I'm stuck at this part: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#run-your-new-load-balanced-app

I use `curl -4 http://localhost` but i get a `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused` error.

output of previous step:
`docker service ps getstartedlab_web`

```
ID                  NAME                  IMAGE                      NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
kqu5qggifnlm        getstartedlab_web.1   s1mpl3/get-started:part2   moby                Running             Running 29 minutes ago                       
prhrmm6hpop3        getstartedlab_web.2   s1mpl3/get-started:part2   moby                Running             Running 29 minutes ago                       
ytrwy5gxp2rk        getstartedlab_web.3   s1mpl3/get-started:part2   moby                Running             Running 29 minutes ago                       
mayvauijghbj        getstartedlab_web.4   s1mpl3/get-started:part2   moby                Running             Running 29 minutes ago                       
r625x2k7n6ta        getstartedlab_web.5   s1mpl3/get-started:part2   moby                Running             Running 29 minutes ago
```

So `error` and `ports` are empty.

What should I analyse to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part 4 when you deploy to your swarm, you get an URL with `docker-machine ls`.

```
NAME    ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
myvm1   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.10.0-ce   
myvm2   -        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.101:2376           v17.10.0-ce
```

Change in docker-compose.yml file `80:80` to `4000:80`

Use `192.168.99.100:4000` and it should be working.